# An update causes blue screen on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bsod, windows-update

This question is related to this other one: [Blue screen 'inaccessible boot device' on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1198226/blue-screen-inaccessible-boot-device-on-windows-10)

I now have two PC with a blue screen on startup with `inaccessible boot device`.

Both of them are of model `HP Compaq 8100 Elite Small Form Factor`. I suspect this is due to the last update KB4015217.

For the moment I deactivated the `Windows Update` service on the remaining computers of that model.

In the computers that cannot boot into Windows, I can access the command line via `Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Command Prompt`.

How can I use that command line to uninstall a specific Windows Update ?

`dism /image:D:\ /get-packages` gives me the list of packages installed, but `dism /image:D:\ /remove-package:Package_for_RollupFix...` fails with `Access denied`.

Comment: Have you tried to use your Windows 10 recovery disk to boot into Windows 10 and remove that update? You can also create a [System Repair Disk](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/36083-create-system-repair-disc-windows-10-a.html) to troubleshoot.

Comment: I only have the original installation disk. I do not have a recovery disk.

Comment: Any reason you cannot make one?

Comment: How is it possible to remove an update, if I'm not able to boot into the Windows installation ?

Comment: No, I will make a System repair disk to see what I can achieve with it.

Comment: Please do not close this question as too broad. I just edited it to narrow it down.